# How to send file over a socket in Dart

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter

I am trying to send a binary file like image or pdf over a socket.
I have tried following:

```
   file.readAsBytesSync().forEach((f) {
     socket.write(f);
   });
```

And

```
   socket.write(file.readAsBytesSync());
```

But I receive a list of integers instead of a binary file.
Code given below in JAVA works fine and receiving port gets file in correct format

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
    dos.write(buffer);
}

fis.close();
dos.close();
```

I am trying to figure out what would be Dart equivalent of above java code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: bro can you tell how you receive this file as a socket client sorry off-topic question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct code:

```
Socket s = await Socket.connect(host, port);
await s.addStream(file.openRead());
print("ok: data written");
```

Comment: Worked like charm, Thanks :)